# How to match the corners of a decorated rectangle in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

This may look duplicate but I'm trying to draw a specific bump-decorated rectangle for an invitation card on the basis of the following picture:

[image: Desired decorated rectangle]

So, I've been using the decoration library of tikz, but no matter the values I set for rounding corners, amplitude and segment, I can't match the corners of the decorated rectangle as I want. The result looks more of like a cloud rather than I expect it to be.
[image: Result]

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[paperwidth=15cm, paperheight=10cm, top=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, positioning}

\begin{document}


\thispagestyle{empty}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    %Outside corners
    \node[anchor=45,below=0.5cm, xshift=1.5cm] (SD) at (current page.45) {};
        \node[anchor=135,below=0.5cm,xshift=-1.5cm] (SI)at (current page.135) {};
        \node[anchor=225,above=0.5cm,xshift=-1.5cm] (II)at (current page.225) {};
        \node[anchor=315,above=0.5cm,xshift=1.5cm] (ID)at (current page.315) {};
        %Inside corners
        \node[] (RSD) [below=10pt, left of=SD, xshift=20pt] {};
        \node[] (RSI) [below right of= SI] {};
        \node[] (RII) [above right of= II] {};
        \node[] (RID) [above left of =ID] {};



        \draw[thick, rounded corners=7mm, decorate, decoration={bumps, segment length=7mm, amplitude=5}]  (SD) rectangle (II) [sharp corners] {};
%--(ID)--(II)--(SI)} {};
     \draw[thick] (RSD) rectangle (RII) {}; 



   \end{tikzpicture}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Ch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `decorations` you can always draw the frame `by hand` which means:

1. draw and fill rectangle with external dimensions
2. draw and fill as many circle you need
3. draw and fill inner rectangle
4. fill your invitation card

[image]

Following code shows my solution. It uses `standalone` package and card dimension are fixed with `tikzpicture` coordinates instead of using `geometry` package. I think it's easier this way.

```
\documentclass[tikz, 10pt, margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (SD) at (-6,5);
\coordinate (SI) at (6,5);
\coordinate (ID) at (-6,-5);
\coordinate (II) at (6,-5);

\coordinate[below right = 5mm of SD] (RSD);
\coordinate[below left = 5mm of SI] (RSI);
\coordinate[above right = 5mm of ID] (RID);
\coordinate[above left = 5mm of II] (RII);

\fill[red] (SD) rectangle (II);

\foreach \i in {0,2,...,60}{
    \fill[red] ([xshift=\i*2mm]SD) circle (2mm); 
    \fill[red] ([xshift=\i*2mm]ID) circle (2mm); 
}

\foreach \i in {0,2,...,50}{
    \fill[red] ([yshift=-\i*2mm]SD) circle (2mm); 
    \fill[red] ([yshift=-\i*2mm]SI) circle (2mm); 
}

\fill[black!10] (RSD) rectangle (RII);

\node[font=\Huge\calligra] {Happy birthday!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: After some coordinate adjustments I'm able to get your code to work as I wanted. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @Charlie Glad to help you. Enjoy your celebration ;-)