# Implementation of "clouds" for notes in the text

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, formatting, vertical-alignment

It is hard to describe what I want in a setence, better take a look on how I usually write down (lecture) notes.

[image]

I want to point your attention to these little "clouds" which contain some useful, but not necessary information about a sentence, for example.

It is important to me that I have these notes *in* the text and not *"outside"* (as a footnote or so).

Also notice that notes are placed wherever there is enough space.

We already have examples of such clouds here on TEX.SX:
[cloud examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329043/rectanglar-cloud-shaped-node-in-tikz)

So I search for something like a `\stackrel` or `\overbrace` command that does all the alignment and spacing for me (obviously it would take ages to align manually with all those clouds otherwise).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: **SUPPLEMENT** added at end for `twoside` version.

Unless you want to spend all your time manually placing text so as to wrap around your clouds, I suggest combining it with a `\marginpar` mechanism.  The only change to the layout I did was to decrease the `\textwidth` to leave room for the clouds.

```
\documentclass{article}
\textwidth=\dimexpr\textwidth-1in\relax
\usepackage{tikz,tabto,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\newcommand\margincloud[1]{{%
  \tabto{\textwidth}%
  \llap{%
    \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{.5pt}{\dp\strutbox}%
    \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\TabPrevPos\relax}{.5pt}%
    \kern-3pt
    \smash{\rlap{\rotatebox[origin=lb]{45}{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{60pt}{.5pt}}}}}%
  \tabto*{\TabPrevPos}%
  \marginpar{%
    \smash{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [cloud, fill=blue!5, draw,cloud puffs=10,cloud puff arc=120, 
       aspect=1.5, inner ysep=1em]{\parbox{1in}{\raggedright#1}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }}%
}}

\begin{document}
This is a test\margincloud{My marginnote of some length} of a cloudy
marginpar.  I will continue to write so as to make sure that the line
is appropriately set at the right height. \lipsum[1]

Now I get to try it again, to see if it still works.  Let us do it here%
\margincloud{I would like a longer marginnote to see how this works}
and see. \lipsum[2]

Finally, we get to try it one last time on the page.  I will work
my way a bit into the paragraph, in order to see if that makes any
difference at all.  Ok, we prepare for this final test of the page.
Here goes...\margincloud{Boo!} \lipsum[3]
 \end{document}
```

[image]

At the OP's request, a version with dotted connectors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\textwidth=\dimexpr\textwidth-1in\relax
\usepackage{tikz,tabto,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\def\dotfill#1{\cleaders\hbox to #1{\scalebox{1.4}{.}}\hfill}
\newcommand\dotline[2][.5em]{\leavevmode\hbox to #2{\dotfill{#1}\hfil}}
\newcommand\margincloud[1]{{%
  \tabto{\textwidth}%
  \llap{\raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}{%
    \dotline{\dimexpr\textwidth-\TabPrevPos\relax}%
    \kern-3pt
    \smash{\rlap{\rotatebox[origin=lb]{45}{\dotline[.7em]{60pt}}}}}}%
  \tabto*{\TabPrevPos}%
  \marginpar{%
    \smash{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [cloud, fill=blue!5, draw,cloud puffs=10,cloud puff arc=120, 
       aspect=1.5, inner ysep=1em]{\parbox{1in}{\raggedright#1}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }}%
}}
\sloppy
\begin{document}
This is a test\margincloud{My marginnote of some length} of a cloudy
marginpar.  I will continue to write so as to make sure that the line
is appropriately set at the right height. \lipsum[1]

Now I get to try it again, to see if it still works.  Let us do it here%
\margincloud{I would like a longer marginnote to see how this works}
and see. \lipsum[2]

Finally, we get to try it one last time on the page.  I will work
my way a bit into the paragraph, in order to see if that makes any
difference at all.  Ok, we prepare for this final test of the page.
Here goes...\margincloud{Boo!} \lipsum[3]
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Better yet, a version with bubbles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\textwidth=\dimexpr\textwidth-1in\relax
\usepackage{tikz,tabto,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\def\dotfill#1#2{\cleaders\hbox to #1{\scalebox{#2}{$\circ$}}\hfill}
\newcommand\dotline[3][.6em]{\leavevmode\hbox to #2{\dotfill{#1}{#3}\hfil}}
\newcommand\margincloud[1]{{%
  \tabto{\textwidth}%
  \llap{\raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}{%
    \dotline{\dimexpr\textwidth-\TabPrevPos\relax}{.6}%
    \kern-3pt
    \smash{\rlap{\rotatebox[origin=lb]{45}{\dotline[.8em]{60pt}{1}}}}}}%
  \tabto*{\TabPrevPos}%
  \marginpar{%
    \smash{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [cloud, fill=blue!5, draw,cloud puffs=10,cloud puff arc=120, 
       aspect=1.5, inner ysep=1em]{\parbox{1in}{\raggedright#1}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }}%
}}
\sloppy
\begin{document}
This is a test\margincloud{My marginnote of some length} of a cloudy
marginpar.  I will continue to write so as to make sure that the line
is appropriately set at the right height. \lipsum[1]

Now I get to try it again, to see if it still works.  Let us do it here%
\margincloud{I would like a longer marginnote to see how this works}
and see. \lipsum[2]

Finally, we get to try it one last time on the page.  I will work
my way a bit into the paragraph, in order to see if that makes any
difference at all.  Ok, we prepare for this final test of the page.
Here goes...\margincloud{Boo!} \lipsum[3]
 \end{document}
```

[image]

**SUPPLEMENT** twoside version (using lines, per OP request)

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
%\usepackage[left=2.5in,right=2.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,tabto,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\def\dotfill#1#2{\xleaders\hbox to #1{\scalebox{#2}{$\circ$}}\hfill}
\newcommand\dotline[3][.6em]{\leavevmode\hbox to #2{\dotfill{#1}{#3}\hfil}}
\newcommand\margincloud{\ifodd\thepage\relax\expandafter\rmargincloud
  \else\expandafter\lmargincloud\fi}
\newcommand\lmargincloud[1]{{%
  \tabto*{0pt}%
  \smash{\rlap{%
    \smash{\llap{\rotatebox[origin=rb]{-45}{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{60pt}{.5pt}}}}%
    \kern-2.5pt
    \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\TabPrevPos}{.5pt}%
        \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{.5pt}{\dp\strutbox}}}%
  \tabto{\TabPrevPos}%
  \marginpar{%
    \smash{\makebox[\marginparwidth][r]{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [cloud, fill=blue!5, draw,cloud puffs=10,cloud puff arc=120, 
       aspect=1.5, inner ysep=1em]{\parbox{1in}{\raggedright#1}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }}}%
}}
\newcommand\rmargincloud[1]{{%
  \tabto{\textwidth}%
  \smash{\llap{%
    \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{.5pt}{\dp\strutbox}%
    \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\TabPrevPos\relax}{.5pt}%
    \kern-2.5pt
    \smash{\rlap{\rotatebox[origin=lb]{45}{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{60pt}{.5pt}}}}}}%
  \tabto*{\TabPrevPos}%
  \marginpar{%
    \smash{\makebox[\marginparwidth][l]{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [cloud, fill=blue!5, draw,cloud puffs=10,cloud puff arc=120, 
       aspect=1.5, inner ysep=1em]{\parbox{1in}{\raggedright#1}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }}}%
}}
\sloppy
\begin{document}

This is a test\margincloud{My marginnote of some length} of a cloudy
marginpar.  I will continue to write so as to make sure that the line
is appropriately set at the right height. \lipsum[1]

Now I get to try it again, to see if it still works.  Let us do it here%
\margincloud{I would like a longer marginnote to see how this works}
and see. \lipsum[2]

Finally, we get to try it one last time on the page.  I will work
my way a bit into the paragraph, in order to see if that makes any
difference at all.  Ok, we prepare for this final test of the page.
Here goes...\margincloud{Boo!} \lipsum[3]

\clearpage
This is a test\margincloud{My marginnote of some length} of a cloudy
marginpar.  I will continue to write so as to make sure that the line
is appropriately set at the right height. \lipsum[1]

Now I get to try it again, to see if it still works.  Let us do it here%
\margincloud{I would like a longer marginnote to see how this works}
and see. \lipsum[2]

Finally, we get to try it one last time on the page.  I will work
my way a bit into the paragraph, in order to see if that makes any
difference at all.  Ok, we prepare for this final test of the page.
Here goes...\margincloud{Boo!} \lipsum[3]
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is a good idea. Can I make the line dotted like in my picture?

Comment: @Aericura Please see my edit.

Comment: @Aericura Wait for it... a version with bubbles!

Comment: @steven-b-segletes Follow-up question: When using the `twoside` option in the geometry package, the placement of the line to the cloud gets messed up. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Aericura Might be worthy of a new question, but let me ask...do you want the clouds on the left on evenside, or always on the right?

Comment: @steven-b-segletes The clouds on an even side should be on the left, on an odd on the right.

Comment: @Aericura That means you will have to compress margins on both sides...  still thinking on it.

Comment: Okay, I think I will open up a new question in order to clarify what I mean.

Comment: @Aericura  Please see the **SUPPLEMENT** to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, how are you so fast and always answer instantly? :)

Comment: @Aericura You're welcome.  I'm getting old, so if I don't get it out fast, I forget what I was doing...LOL!

Comment: @steven-b-segletes Unfortunately, I have to annoy you once more :( you have secretly convinced me that the version with straight lines looks best (the first in your many examples). How can I change the code above two make twosided straight line clouds?

Comment: @Aericura Done.  Leaving for the day.

Answer (score 5):

With `tikz` and `tikzmark` you can do such things.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,shapes.symbols,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{thought dots/.style={decoration={markings,
      mark=between positions 4pt and 0.95 step 9pt
      with
      {
        \draw (0,0) circle[radius=2pt];
      }
},decorate}}
\begin{document}
Standard philosophy $\displaystyle (M,\sigma_M)
\xrightarrow[\tikzmarknode{n}{\mathrm{nervously}}]{\mathrm{study}}(M,\sigma_M)$
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\path[thought dots] (n) -- ++(0.5,-1) node[below,cloud,draw,align=center,aspect=2,inner sep=0pt]{study structure\\
of sets by studying\\ maps between them};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can address the alignment problem with either shapepar or wrapfig or something along those lines. Which of these options suits you best may only be gauged once you provide us with an MWE, from which we can see which packages you are using and so on. The following is to give you an idea.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,shapes.symbols,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{thought dots/.style={decoration={markings,
      mark=between positions 4pt and 0.95 step 9pt
      with
      {
        \draw (0,0) circle[radius=2pt];
      }
},decorate},iCloud/.style={cloud,draw,align=center,aspect=2,inner sep=0pt}}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{3}
\section{Measurable maps}
Standard philosophy $\displaystyle (M,\sigma_M)
\xrightarrow[\tikzmarknode{n}{\mathrm{nervously}}]{\mathrm{study}}(M,\sigma_M)$

\begin{wrapfigure}[10]{r}[10pt]{6cm}
\tikzmarknode[iCloud]{nn}{study structure\\
of sets by studying\\ maps between them}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\path[thought dots] (n) -- (nn);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
$\triangleright$ measurable maps

a map $f:M\to N$ is called measurable if \dots \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want them in the margin, then I'd use `tikzpagenodes`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1.5in,bottom=1.5in,right=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,shapes.symbols,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{thought dots/.style={decoration={markings,
      mark=between positions 4pt and 1-4pt step 9pt
      with
      {
        \draw (0,0) circle[radius=2pt];
      }
},decorate},iCloud/.style={cloud,draw,align=center,aspect=2,inner sep=0pt}}
\newcounter{clouds}
\newcommand{\AddThought}[3][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\stepcounter{clouds}
\node[iCloud,anchor=west,#1] (cloud-\number\value{clouds}) at 
(#2.south-|current page text area.east)
{#3};
\path[thought dots] (#2) -- (cloud-\number\value{clouds});
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{3}
\section{Measurable maps}
Standard philosophy $\displaystyle (M,\sigma_M)
\xrightarrow[\tikzmarknode{n}{\mathrm{nervously}}]{\mathrm{study}}(M,\sigma_M)$
\AddThought{n}{study structure\\
of sets by studying\\ maps between them}

$\triangleright$ measurable maps

a map $f:M\to N$ is called measurable if \dots \lipsum[1]

Something about \tikzmarknode{d}{ducks}
\AddThought[yshift=-1cm]{d}{Why always\\
ducks? Don't we\\ have enough\\ ducks?}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, but now I have a problem: When putting dummy text after your example, the text.gets placed over the cloud (study nervously :))) Can I place the text around the cloud?

Comment: @Aericura Your comment was 23 seconds early, I added an example addressing this.

Comment: Ah, I see, that's a great way of doing it (I was looking for something like this)! Thank you!