# Is there a way to make cloudy tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox, border

What I mean is when we make tcolorboxes they are in the shape of box with straight lines by using borderline command we could change how far away it is or how it looks.
For example:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,arc=3mm,boxrule=1.5mm,frame hidden,colback=blue!10!white,borderline={1mm}{0mm}{blue,dotted} ]  
     
\lipsum[2]  
 
\end{tcolorbox}
```

In this code, we're making different things but importantly we make our borderline dotted and blue I want to make it curly like a sine wavy or cloudy? Is there anything for this?

**Edit after comment:** Idea was this[image: Idea was this]

Comment: Try the `frame code=<tikz drawing code>` option.

Comment: Hope based on `muzimuzhi Z` suggestion you solved the issue, if not so, can you show a image of your requirement, sorry it is not clear for me....

Comment: oh i didn't but i believe what he said is just enough.I checked the manuel for tcolorbox probably it would work but i just give up on the idea it was taking to much time and i'm very rusty on latex so that is that. If i continue using after my work is done probably i would give it a try

Comment: @MadyYuvi I added a picture

Comment: `tcolorbox` does "an accentuated colored text box with rounded
corners" (manual, p 12), the core code being a bunch of `\pgfpathlineto`s with (adjustable) arcs on the ends. A TikZ cloud node with some rectangular nodes emulating a `tcolorbox` might work.

Comment: @OğuzhanKılıç Hi, I think with umilty that the answer of Cicada it is the best. Can you, please, switch the green check mark to Cicada user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add one detail to @Sebastiano's creative solution, making the cloud fill and the tcolorbox frame and background all the same colour perhaps gives the cloud a more 'cloudy' feel.

[image: cloud with tcb]

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) [draw,cloud,cloud puffs=15, aspect=2.5, cloud puff arc=120,inner sep = 0pt,fill=blue!10,text width=14em,text height=2ex] {%
\begin{tcolorbox}[fonttitle=\bfseries\large,coltitle=black,colbacktitle=blue!10,title=Title Text,colframe=blue!10,colback=blue!10,width=12em]
An idea goes here \ldots
\end{tcolorbox}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) [draw,cloud,cloud puffs=15, aspect=2.5, cloud puff arc=120,inner sep = 0pt,fill=blue!10,text width=14em,text height=2ex] {%
\begin{tcolorbox}[fonttitle=\bfseries\large,coltitle=black,colbacktitle=blue!15,title=Title Text,colframe=blue!30,colback=blue!20,width=12em]
An idea goes here \ldots
\end{tcolorbox}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice one...love it....

Answer (score 5):

Surely it is not very beautiful my cloud but this it is the result that I have obtained.
You can change:

1. the parameter of `scale=.7` to increase or decrease the size frame clasic `tcolorbox`;
2. The number of the `cloud puffs=...`;

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,fit}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) at (0,0) [inner sep = 0pt,scale=.7] {\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=Text,
attach boxed title to top left]
\lipsum[1].\end{tcolorbox}
};
\node [draw, inner sep=0pt, cloud, cloud puffs=20, aspect=1.8,fit=(a)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent idea!

Comment: Wow....Merry X-Mas

Comment: @MadyYuvi My sincere greetings and the best wishes :-)

Comment: @Cicada But it is not true....tcolorbox not have the cloud and I have only thought to create a outside cloudy. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

This is more an exercise than a useful solution, but `frame code app` allow to define any kind of path as tcolorbox border.

In this particular case, a combination of a `fit` node with a `cloud` shape is proposed.

You can see from the example that the resulting `tcolorbox` won't have any consideration with margins and surrounding text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.symbols}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{mycloud}[1][]{%
    enhanced, colback=red!5!white,
    colframe=red!75!black, fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=black,
    frame code app={\node[fit=(frame), draw=tcbcolframe, 
        fill=tcbcolback, cloud, inner sep=0pt, 
        cloud puffs=15, cloud puff arc=120, aspect=3] {};},
    #1}
        
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{mycloud}[title=my title]
\lipsum[2]
\end{mycloud}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A second exercise could be to adapt answers in [Rectanglar cloud shaped node in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/329043/1952) to `tcolorbox` if a *biscuit* form is accepted as equivalent to *cloud*

Comment: This is very nice and I appreciated very much.